# Why does JavaFX low level binding not using lambdas and functional interfaces?

Tags: java, lambda, javafx-8

I read about javaFx low level binding usage  and I have a question.

Currently in order to create a new Integer property I would need to do something like this:

```
SimpleIntegerProperty simpleIntegerProperty = new SimpleIntegerProperty(5);
IntegerBinding x = new IntegerBinding(){
    {
       super.bind(simpleIntegerProperty);
    }
    @Override
    protected int computeValue(){
            return 456 * simpleIntegerProperty.get();
    }
};
```

This is quite annoying.

Why not take advantage of the lambda API?

Providing something like so:

```
interface ValuedBinding<X>{
    X computeValue();

    default Property<X> bind(ObservableValue<X> xObservableValue){
        //blaa...
        return null;
    }

    default <E extends Property<X>> E bindBidirectional(E xProperty){
        //blaa...
        return null;
    }
}

interface IntegerBinding2 extends ValuedBinding<Number> {
 // dada....
}
```

And usage like:

```
    IntegerBinding2 integerBinding = () -> 5;
    integerBinding.bindBidirectional(simpleIntegerProperty);
```

Comment: A guess: Javafx 8 is based on Javafx 2.x, where lambdas did not exist yet. Maybe something like this will be available in future versions...

Answer (score 3):

The functionality you are looking for is (more or less) provided in the [`Bindings`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html) class by the [`createIntegerBinding` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#createIntegerBinding-java.util.concurrent.Callable-javafx.beans.Observable...-):

```
IntegerProperty simpleIntegerProperty = new SimpleIntegerProperty(5);
IntegerBinding integerBinding = Bindings.createIntegerBinding( () -> 
    simpleIntegerProperty.get() * 456, simpleIntegerProperty );
```

and also (for the specific example you use) by the [`IntegerExpression`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/IntegerExpression.html) class:

```
IntegerProperty simpleIntegerProperty = new SimpleIntegerProperty(5);
IntegerBinding x = simpleIntegerProperty.multiply(456);
```

The actual code you showed confuses bindings and properties: bindings cannot be set, as (for example) they might represent expressions depending on multiple other observable values. Consequently they do not, and cannot, have a `bindBidirectional` method, as properties do.

In general, using default methods in a widespread fashion as you suggest is probably not advisable. Default methods cannot be added to interfaces in a way that guarantees that existing code doesn't break (read, e.g., [this paper by Brian Goetz](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/Defender%20Methods%20v4.pdf), specifically section 6). Most of the time it is probably fine, but it is sensible to minimize their use. In this case, a factory method can easily be provided to allow lambdas to be used, and this is the mechanism the JavaFX designers chose.